# Android Studio Can't find file in Assets Folder

Tags: android, android-studio

New to Android Studio and am stumbling on fairly simple things. I'm trying to open a file that I have stored in the assets folder of my project. I get a `FileNotFoundException` error. How should I correctly store and reference the file?

Here is the method that crashes:

```
    public void saveKey(String outFile, String pubKeyFilename) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        File out = new File(outFile);
        File publicKeyFile = new File(pubKeyFilename);

        // read public key to be used to encrypt the AES key
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)publicKeyFile.length()];

        // crashes here
        new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile).read(encodedKey);

        //...
}
```

And here is how I am calling it:

```
EncryptRSA cipher = new EncryptRSA();
cipher.saveKey("temp", "public.der");
```

The file is saved in my assets folder like this:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to open a file that I have stored in the assets folder of
>   my project.

To access file from assets folder use `AssetManager` for getting InputStream using file name:

```
AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assManager.open(pubKeyFilename);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is using the assets folder the best way to do this? Is there a default location that I can store the file in, and then reference it without having to list the entire file path?

Comment: @Randall: With apk there is no other location to add files but you can also use `res/raw` folder for adding files